# PlotlyDash embedding data into html.Details

Tags: python, plotly-dash

im kinda new to Python and Dash.
As i'm interested in Data Analytics I started messing around with Dash.
The plan is to build a stock dashboard but i'm stuck with some things...
I want to have an dcc.Input box where you can put a Ticker and submit with html.button,
later on I want to display data from multiple stocks in different html.Details so my Question is
how to achieve that.
I'm not getting to far because I don't understand the callback.
When trying the provied code I get **Error:Callback error updating table.children - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'**

Whats the correct way to turn input into a datatable and put in a html.Details

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text', placeholder='Enter Stock ticker'),
    html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
    html.Div(id='table')
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('table', 'children')],
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('input', 'value')]
)

def update_table(input_value, n_clicks):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(input_value.upper())
    history = ticker.history(period='max')
    return html.Div([
        html.Details(
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id='tickerdata',
                columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in history.columns],
                data = history,
            )
        )
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error was that the order in which the callback functions were received and the arguments of the update function were not in the correct order. n_clicks is trying to capitalize the number and the error occurred. The next error is that the data frame needs to be changed to a dictionary in order to be displayed in the table. Also, the data in the stocks is indexed by date, so the date column needs to be unindexed in order to display it.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text', placeholder='Enter Stock ticker'),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit_btn',n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='table')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'children'),
    [Input('submit_btn', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('input', 'value')]
)
def update_table(n_clicks, input_value):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(input_value.upper())
    history = ticker.history(period='max')
    history.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return html.Div([
        html.Details(
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id='tickerdata',
                columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in history.columns],
                data = history.to_dict('records'),
                fixed_rows={'headers':True}
            )
        )
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your time.